# jQuery doesn't work on table generated from response of Java servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I have a curious problem with a table generated from the servlet response.

The thing is:

I have an HTML page with a button, the user press the button and an Ajax call starts towards a Java Servlet. The servlet responds with a simple HTML table that appears inside a `div` under the button.

I have created a simple `jQuery` function that at every click on the elements `TD` print a message in Javascript console log. But at the click on the `TD` it doesn't do anything.

The strange thing is that on the same page there is the same HTML table (not generated by javascript but contained in the HTML page) and in that case, the `jQuery` function works fine.

Here the code of the table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    console.log("testlog");
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer it is easier solution than chaining the click on ajax call response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to put your script after you render the ajax call and not when document ready event.
well i dont know how your code looks but do something like that

```js
$.ajax({
//options
}).done(function(res){

  $('body').append(res)
  $("td").on('click',function() {
    console.log("testlog");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the dynamicaly generated `table` does not have event listener because it loaded later than DOM you cannot listen to click directly on `td` but either on whole document or on wrapper of the table here is working example.

I am loading table in .5s to simulate ajax.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#wrapper').append(`<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>`)
}, 500)

//works
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'td', function() {
  console.log('this works')
})

//this does not
$('td').on('click', function() {
  console.log('this does not work')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

always use `.on` in this case

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").on('click',function() {
    console.log("testlog");
  });
});
```